# Comparar Strings y sacar indice de caracter diferente con Streams en Java

Tags: java, string, stream

Necesito comparar 2 strings iguales hasta cierto carácter y devolver como int la posición de ese cambio. He intentado esto pero no funciona

```
String a = "buenosdiaspepe";
        String b = "buenosdiasjuan";
        List<Integer> salida = IntStream.of().filter(i -> a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(salida);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece más natural una solución con un `for`:

```
int i;
// se asume ambas cadenas son de la misma longitud
for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    // terminal al encontrar diferencia en la posición i
    if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) break;
}

System.out.println(i);
```

---

**Actualización**

En tu código solo faltaría cambiar `of()` por `range()`.

```
List<Integer> diferencias =
        IntStream
        .range(0, a.length())
        .filter(i -> a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(diferencias);
```

Comment: Lo es, pero es un ejercicio de practica el cual me obliga a hacerlo mediante streams.

Comment: Ok, ya actualicé la respuesta.